# Searching for existing field available or not in shapefile by ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes

I want to check existing fields in a shapefile by ArcPy. I want to test for two fields, named "Northing" and "Easting". If both fields are present then it's okay, else if one or both of the fields are missing, then I want to find this, and add that field  to the shapefile by ArcPy.

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to specify how you want the fields defined (number of places left and right of the decimal) for the `arcpy.AddField_management` directive.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ListFields](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/listfields.htm) with [sets](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_set_issubset.asp):

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\folder\file.shp'

all_fields = {f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc)} #Create a set of all fieldnames

if {'Northing','Easting'}.issubset(all_fields):
    print 'All fields are here'
else:
    print 'Field(s) are missing'
```

Or simply:

```
all_fields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]
    
for fieldname in ['Northing','Easting']:
    if not fieldname in all_fields:
        print '{0} is missing'.format(fieldname)
```

Comment: You probably want to use `str.upper()` on the `fieldname` and upgrade the test strings, in case a `.shp.xml` isn't present to generate mixed-case aliases.